# How to click CSS in Selenium

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to `click` a `div` heading but having some difficulty, below is the `CSS`

```
html body#RuntimeFormBody form#Form1 div#tblContainer div#Content div#ContainerCell div#ContainerSizeGuide div.WebControl.ctTabbedFolder.ControlViewportDESKTOP div#TabbedFolder1 div.contentholder span#TabbedFolder1Page1.TabHL.TabSelected div a
```

the code is just to `click` the above so I don't think I need to supply that as it won't really help.

I have got help for something similar which was

```
html body.CommunityBody form#Form1 div.MainCommunityTable.MobileLayoutBlock div div div.NarrowCommunity span.AddinSpan div.AddIn.atScreens.AddInViewportDESKTOP.AddInDisplayBLOCK div#AddInMyQuickLinks.AddInCollapsible.ui-accordion.ui-widget.ui-helper-reset div#ui-accordion-AddInMyQuickLinks-panel-0.AddInMain.ui-accordion-content.ui-helper-reset.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-bottom.ui-accordion-content-active span ul.NoIndent li.NoBullet.jms-bullet h3 a img
```

And the solution was below.

```
@FindBy(css = "li:nth-child(1).NoBullet.jms-bullet> h3>a[href^='javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen']")
```

So I am looking for a similar solution.

Thanks in advance for your assistance! :)

adding HTML

```
<img width="15" border="0" align="ABSMIDDLE" alt="Click to edit Payroll Company" onkeydown="xCode=String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).charCodeAt(0);if (xCode == 32){$(this).click()};" onclick="$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').lookupID='db775dbd-f0c4-4c15-9280-d8e881a728c0';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').screenID='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').caption='Select Lookup Value - Payroll Company';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').filterControl=0;$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').filterFieldType='0';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').filterFieldCaption='';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').filterValueDataView='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').filterValueTable='';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').filterValueField='';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').filterFieldOnScreen='False';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').isChangesMade='TRUE';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').currentRecordID='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';if ($HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').filterBySystemFieldValue==undefined) $HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').filterBySystemFieldValue='';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').impersonationId='';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').impersonationToken='';$HRnet('PAYROLLCOMPANY1').show();" style="POSITION:RELATIVE;TOP:0px;LEFT:2px;cursor:pointer;" tabindex="1" title="Click to edit Payroll Company" src="/V14_ST1/Application/Images/btnLookup.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just

```
By.cssSelector("#TabbedFolder1Page1 div a")
```

I'm not used to reading CSS like you have it posted. I don't know where that came from. The HTML would be more useful (for me, at least). You may be able to use the below to be more specific.

```
By.cssSelector("#TabbedFolder1Page1 > div > a")
```

Comment: Hi I've add html, but I'll try your suggestion above.